# Why Is Gremlin Not Allowed Even Though in allowedLanguages?

Tags: gremlin, orientdb, docker-container, gremlin-server, orientdb3.0

## Problem

Why is the [Gremlin Language](https://orientdb.com/docs/latest/gremlin/Gremlin.html?highlight=gremlin#gremlin-api) not allowed in [OrientDB-Studio](https://orientdb.com/docs/latest/studio/) when I've set the parameter to allow?

I had this working before I recreated, but now when I follow the steps I still get denied Gremlin.
If you know what I'm doing wrong in my steps, or how I can ask the question better, Please let me know in the comments, so I can improve the Stack Overflow questions.

[image: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find a script executor requester for language: gremlin]

## Reproduction

### Repo Steps

1. Create an [OrientDB Docker-container](https://hub.docker.com/_/orientdb)
2. Edit its `/orientdb/config/orientdb-server-config.xml`

   1. From: `<parameter name="allowedLanguages" value="SQL"/>`
   2. To:  `<parameter name="allowedLanguages" value="SQL,GREMLIN"/>`
3. Startup this OrientDB container
4. Login to a OrientDB-database on [OrientDB-Studio](http://localhost:2480/studio/index.html#/)
5. Execute-and-Verify `` SELECT count(*) FROM `V` `` SQL-Command
6. Execute-and-Verify `g.V().count()` Gremlin-Command
7. Results

   1. Expected: `g.V().count()` would printout
   2. Actually: Error Toast-Message `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find a script executor requester for language: gremlin`

### Tried

1. Deleting-and-recreating Docker-container
2. Restarting Docker-container (after editing-and-saving)

   1. This works for Neo4j's Docker-container to startup, due to startup procedure
3. Stopping-and-Starting Docker-container (after editing-and-saving)